# PHP conditional print request issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to implement the script below to print the images on the supposed pages but it still doesn't print the image, it shows it as a dead image link instead. I tried changing the image path, yet it didn't work.

```
<?php
    if ($currentpage == '/services/')
        print('<img src="path/to/services.png" alt=""/>');
    elseif ($currentpage == 'contact.php')
        print('<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>');
    else
        print('<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>');
?>
```

Comment: Well this is hard to troubleshoot for us, but I've had problems where the image was saved as .JPG (with caps). Can you verify the image name is exactly as you're trying to reference it? Also, can you access the image by navigating to www.yoursite.com/path/to/image.png ???

Comment: Tim looked at it and it's as correct as it should be. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one explanation and that is that the path is wrong. Right click the dead image and open it in a new window and see what the link is. Then you probably can figure out how you should change the path to get it right.

Comment: MrAzulay it takes me to the home page whenever I do that. here is the link http://siteripe.com/services/

Comment: Probably because that's the behaviour when a file isn't found. Right click and copy image location instead and you should see it.